# Trouble putting lemmatized words into a list

Tags: python

So I am working with a lemmatizer in Python, `pystempel` to be exact. And I am trying to lemmatize words in a text file and write the values all down in a list, so I can do some further work with the lemmatized list. However, I can't get the lemmatizer to actually change the value of these words.

```py
import string
from stempel import StempelStemmer

stemmer = StempelStemmer.polimorf()

for word in *text file*:
 (stemmer.stem(word))
```

Something like this doesen't work because I think it just lemmatizes the words and does nothing else. Can someone help out and tell me how I could lemmatize each word from the text file and put them into a list that I can use later on?

Comment: Hello, it seems that you are referring to a stemmer as a "lemmatizer", though there is a bit of a difference. Stemming refers to cutting off parts of a word that would obscure its meaning to a computer, like 'ed' at the end of the word 'turned'. Lemmatization refers to finding the root meaning of a word. For example, the word `murder` might be turned to `kill`.

Comment: I'm the author [pystempel stemmer](https://github.com/dzieciou/pystempel) and here's an example: `stemmed_word = stemmer(word)`. As you can see stemmer is returned a new string, `stemmer_word` rather than changing the value of the original string, `word`,  in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are an immutable datatype, you cannot change their value. Your lemmatizer is probably returning a value that is the new string that has been lemmatized. You should probably take each lemmatized value and append it to a list.
Example:

```
lemmatized = []
for word in text file: 
  lemmatized.append(stemmer.stem(word))
```